# Trying to run a Python script "How do you want to open this ".py" file?" Message

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, cmd, anaconda

I'm just starting out with Python, using it for part of a Physics course.
Downloaded Python3, ran some test scripts I wrote in Notepad+ no problem.
Realised I needed extra libraries (Like NumPy), so I uninstalled Python3 and installed Anaconda3.

Now whenever I try to run a test script from the cmd it comes up with the "How do you want to open this ".py" file?" Message, asking me to select a program. Selecting the Python interpreter doesn't cause any outputs on the cmd.

[image: Computer problems make me sad]

Comment: Just do "python filename.py"

Comment: Also, you don't need to completely reinstall python for numpy. Just run pip install numpy to download it. If that gives an error, download pip with the instructions from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Works like a charm, many thanks. How come the Anaconda installation requires that I add "Python" before the file name? 

And, yeah, I was trying to future proof myself. 

Sorry for the newbish question!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to learn Python, uninstall your ide.  Since you don't seem familiar
with the command shell, keep using notepad++.
To run a python file, go to the folder of your file. Open up CMD in that folder
and run `python yourfile.py`

or open up cmd and run
`python FULLPATHTOFILE.py`

Anaconda is just an "advanced" text editor that provides useful utilities
for programming in python.  Don't try to executing a python file using a
text editor.